# Postgresql: select unique pairs order by other field

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I want to select latest (`order by id desc`) unique pairs `date_start, date_finish`

```
CREATE TABLE some (
    id SERIAL, 
    date_start TIMESTAMP,
    date_finish TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
select date_start, date_finish
from some
group by date_start, date_finish
order by max(id) desc
```

Comment: Yes, That's it! Thank you!